# How does Cordova convert my code to mobile

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have some questions.

Question 1) I know that Cordova is written in plain js. Ionic team stood up and decided to wrap the Cordova plugin and usage of that by writing typescript code and also in Angular. so ionic sits on top of Cordova. both are frameworks, but Cordova is much deeper. Am I right?

Question 2) which one really can convert my code to mobile code? I know mobiles can't understand js/html/css without browsers. So something converts my Ionic code to something. a) what does my code get converted into? b) what really converts my code?

I'm starting ionic development and really wanted to know this first.

Comment: JS is just a syntax. I'd assume it's like every other interpreter/compiler, where it compiles whatever syntax it supports into whatever bytecode its interpreter supports. Like any non-Java solution on Android, there still needs to be a core Java component so the app can be started.

Comment: Lots of related questions here on StackOverflow like: [How does phoneGap (Cordova) work internally, iOS specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12857462/295004) and [Hybrid application development (PhoneGap, Cordova, Ionic) under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37662715/295004)

Answer (score 2):

Ionic its just a mobile development framework so that you can use design components as well as other plugins for developing an application.

When we refer term Cordova its a main core It allows you to use standard web technologies - **HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript** for cross-platform development. Applications execute within wrappers targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant API bindings to access each device's capabilities such as sensors, data, network status, etc.

### Architecture

There are several components to a cordova application. The following diagram shows a high-level view of the cordova application architecture

[image]

**Web view**
The Cordova-enabled WebView may provide the application with its entire user interface. On some platforms, it can also be a component within a larger, hybrid application that mixes the WebView with native application component

**Web App**

This is the part where your application code resides. The application itself is implemented as a web page, by default a local file named index.html, that references CSS, JavaScript, images, media files, or other resources are necessary for it to run. The app executes in a WebView within the native application wrapper, which you distribute to app stores.

For more understanding please visit this article

[https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview)